# Visualforce/javascript how to display apex:repeat results in a specific order

Tags: visualforce

I have an apex custom class that pulls amount, year and name. I'm able to use Apex:repeat to display the {!result}. However i would like to display this data in a specific order using javascript or other way that would allow me to do so. here is part of the vf code.

```
<apex:repeat value="{!results2}" var="name" rows="1">
   <apex:repeat value="{!results2[name]}" var="year"  first="0" >
      <th>
        <script type="text/javascript">
         var d1 = new Date();
         var curYear = d1.getFullYear();
         var firstYear = d1.getFullYear() - 6;
         if({!year} == 3000)
           {document.write("Totals");}
         else if({!year} == curYear)
           {document.write("YTD");}
         else if( {!year} == curYear - 6)
           { document.write(firstYear + " & Prior" ); }
         else
                       { document.write( {!year});}
            </script>
           </th>
       </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you include code on what {!result} is and how you get values for that variable, and also, what order would you like to have the data? 
is it by any date or name, please provide more details so we can help you

Comment: to me it sounds like you will be using SOQL keywords ORDER BY and then the repeat would be on the order you want, but on apex code instead of javascript